# I'm getting a "command not found" error when trying to install "xgboost" in an Ubuntu 16.04 Virtual Machine

Tags: python-3.x, cmake, virtual-machine, ubuntu-16.04, xgboost

I'm trying to install `xgboost` in an Ubuntu 16.04 virtual machine.

I'm following [this guide](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html#building-on-ubuntu-debian) and ran this command:

```
cmake ..
```

I got this error:

```
-bash: cmake: command not found
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you're getting this error because you don't have the `cmake` command installed, you can fix this by running:

```
sudo apt install cmake
```

I don't know if you've missed this but you can also install `xgboost` using `pip` (or in your case `pip3`), like this:

```
pip3 install xgboost
```

**NOTE**: depending on how your user/project is set up you might need to use the `sudo` command to grant `pip3` write privileges to certain (root) directories, if this is the case, you'd use:

```
sudo pip3 install xgboost
```

**NOTE:** if you don't have `pip3` installed, you can install it using:

```
sudo apt install python3 python3-pip
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, using sudo pip3 install xgboost now it works !!! So for the future installation of a package you suggest to me to use pip3 ?

Comment: You're very welcome and if what you're using is a Python library, then yes, I'd suggest using `pip3 search` to look for it, for example `pip3 search flask` would return a list of packages that contain the keyword *"flask"*, you could do the same for *"xgboost"* or any other package you wanted to install.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:george-edison55/cmake-3.x
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install cmake
```

UPDATE: 
Or you can just use pip:

```
sudo pip3 install xgboost
```

Comment: I have obtained this error with the second comman "sudo ... -3.x"  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'